# C# File.AppendText() right after deleting the file fails

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

So this simple `File.AppendText()` method fails

```
using (var writer = File.AppendText(dst)){ ... }
```

when I call it *right after* I manually delete the file with the name `dst`.
Manually here means using my own hand in a file explore.
Also, I am certain that there is no open `StreamWriter`
in the application scope as I am even using `StreamWriter.WriteLine()`
which is not asynchronous.

I could not find a relevant question in StackOverflow, unfortunately.
This situation happened with C# using Xamarin form on Android.
I believe this behaviour could be general enough so that can happen in a random platform using C#. Hence, there should be a proper way to deal with the situation by checking if `File.AppendText()` method can properly open a `StreamWriter`.

Could anyone give me some advice?

Thanks a lot.

p.s. The full lines of the thrown exception follow.

```
System.IO.IOException: 
Could not create file "/storage/emulated/0/Documents/something". 
File already exists.

at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (
System.String path, 
System.IO.FileMode mode, 
System.IO.FileAccess access, 
System.IO.FileShare share, 
System.Int32 bufferSize, 
System.Boolean anonymous, 
System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x001aa] in
/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release
/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs:239 

at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (
System.String path, 
System.IO.FileMode mode, 
System.IO.FileAccess access, 
System.IO.FileShare share, 
System.Int32 bufferSize, 
System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x00000] in
/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/
mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs:106 

at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check)
System.IO.FileStream..ctor(
string,System.IO.FileMode,
System.IO.FileAccess,
System.IO.FileShare,
int,
System.IO.FileOptions)

at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor (
System.String path, 
System.Boolean append, 
System.Text.Encoding encoding, 
System.Int32 bufferSize) [0x00055] in
/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/
external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/IO/StreamWriter.cs:151 

at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor (
System.String path, System.Boolean append) [0x00000] in
/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release
/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/IO/StreamWriter.cs:131 

at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) 
System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(string,bool)

at System.IO.File.AppendText (System.String path) [0x0000e] in
/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release
/external/corefx/src/System.IO.FileSystem/src/System/IO/File.cs:48 

at MyNameSpace.Droid.MyService.MyMethod () [0x001fd] 
in C:\workspace\my_project\my_code.cs:257
```

Comment: Sorry if I am missing something, however, the line of code you are pointing to and the thrown exception appear to be inconsistent. The error is stating that it cannot “create” the file since it already exists. I do not think that that particular exception would be thrown with … `var writer = File.AppendText(dst)`  or even … `File.Create(dst)` … ? … Are you sure that line of code is throwing the exception?

Comment: frankly, this sounds like it could be an issue with the Android filesystem - you are deleting a file then immediately trying to write to it, is that really a use case you need to worry about?

Comment: @Jason 's opinion would be most practical. I thought the same that I should not dig up this further, particularly because deleting it manually and then trying to append would be a rare case. Also, it feels like an Android issue. The file has been deleted by a user manually. The file io system is updating such a modification while I am trying to write in with the same file name.

Comment: To @JohnG , thanks for commenting on that. At the end of the thrown exceptions, you see ```in C:\workspace\my_project\my_code.cs:257```. At that line the ```File.AppendText()``` opens the ```StreamWriter``` which is also indicated right above in the exception lines. This should be an Android issue.

Comment: Nevertheless, I am still curious how an experienced engineer would tackle this problem. How would one specify the exact source of the problem even before coming up with the solution? I want to understand what is precisely causing this problem even though one may never care. This will give me an insight how to deal with the file system better in general. Therefore, I would let this question alive until there is a very good answer.

Answer (score 1):

So, I believe this is an Android issue. The Android version and the hardware are not important aspects of this discussion. A `System.IO.IOException` can happen in any situation in any environment unexpectedly. It is an engineer's responsibility to figure out what can be done in such a situation. I came up with a naive solution, and I post it as an answer.

The problem is the following. An application attempts to call the `File.AppendText()`, `File.CreateText()`, or `File.Copy()` method *right after* the file with the identical name previously existed and a user just deleted. Say, one of the aforementioned methods is called in one second. Then an exception

```
System.IO.IOException: 
Could not create file "/storage/emulated/0/Documents/something". 
File already exists.
```

is thrown at the line where the app is calling `File.AppendText()`, `File.CreateText()`, or `File.Copy()`.
The destination path was generated using

```
string public_dst = Path.Combine(
    Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
    Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDocuments).AbsolutePath,
    "my_file_name");
```

The source file name was generated using

```
string private_src = Path.Combine(
    System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
        System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal),
        $"my_source_file");
```

A naive way to alleviate this problem is to try again after a delay. A server-client networking system would try similar, no? The code reads

```
int CUR_TRIALS =    0;
int MAX_TRIALS =   10;
int INTERVAL   = 1000;  /* in milliseconds */

string str_ex = "";  /* @Console */

while (true)
{
    try
    {
        File.Copy(private_dst, public_dst);
        break;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        str_ex = ex.ToString();
        string known = 
            $"System.IO.IOException: Could not create file " +
            $"\"{public_dst}\". File already exists.";

        bool is_known = str_ex.Contains(known);

        if (is_known && (str_ex != ""))
        {
            #if DEBUG
            Log.Info($"{TAG}.PrivateToPublic()", 
                $"System.IO.IOException: ",
                $"{CUR_TRIALS.ToString("D4")}/" +
                $"{MAX_TRIALS.ToString("D4")}");
            #endif

            Task.Delay(INTERVAL).Wait();
        }
    }

    CUR_TRIALS += 1;
    if (CUR_TRIALS >= MAX_TRIALS)
    {
        #if DEBUG
        Log.Info($"{TAG}.PrivateToPublic()", str_ex);
        #endif

        throw new ApplicationException($"0x00000089");
    }
}
```

I manually specified how many times it can try and what time delay it suspends until it can try again. I easily can reconstruct this problem by deleting the file at the destination path and call one of the aforementioned methods right after it. The suggested routine definitely encounters the `catch` block. It suspends for a second and then it retries. It usually succeed in the very next attempt, so this approach can be practical.

Comment: Seeing this, it reminded me that maybe it can be written into a function, then instead of `File.Copy()` in the function, it accepts delegates to replace that part. That way, a general IO checking method can be done. For every IO-related steps in a process, wrap the codes with this function, so similar checks can be skipped when coding. Still haven't think this through though, there might be some drawbacks that way?

Answer (score 0):

I had do a simple to test the method.

```
  string myfile = @"/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.apptest/cache/NewTextFile2.txt";
// Appending the given texts
   using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(myfile))
   {
   sw.WriteLine("some thing");
   sw.WriteLine("some thing else");
   }
```

If the file's path isn't exited, it will create a file and then append. If the file's path is exited, it will append directly.

Comment: I guess your experiment is supposed to be a general behaviour one expects. I am asking for an idea of how others would deal with my situation if they encounter it in an elegant way. This can be an Android-specific problem, maybe, the version matters, also the hardware matters. In that case, how would one deal with this situation?